# How do I interpret the meaning of the following claims?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I interpret these claims in order to translate them into plain English. They seem a bit ambiguous in their meaning to me.

$$1) \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{N}: \exists y\in\mathbb{N}: (x+y=0)$$

$$2) \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{Z}: \exists y\in\mathbb{Z}: (x+y=0)$$

$$3) \quad \exists y\in\mathbb{N}: \forall x\in\mathbb{N}: (x+y=0)$$

$$4) \quad \exists y\in\mathbb{Q}: \forall x\in\mathbb{Q}: (x+y=0)$$

My interpretation of these claims is that the first means "For all $x$ that are natural numbers, there exists a $y$ in the set of natural numbers such that $x+y=0$.

However, this is where I stop understanding the meaning of this expression. Does this mean that there is *one* $y$ for all existing $x$'s that makes $x+y=0$? Or is it trying to say that There is a specific $y$ for all $x$ which makes $x+y=0$?

So basically is it saying that $y$ is a master key? Or is it saying that there is a specific key ($y$) for each $x$?

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: As @AndréNicolas indicates, your first "interpretation of these claims" anyway 1) and 2), is correct: for each $x$, there is a $y$ (choice of $y$ depending on $x$), such that $x+y=0$. Your "However, ..." paragraph is going off the rails: no, not that, forget about it, **with respect to 1) and 2)**. BUT, 3) and 4) *do* make such claims: they say, there is some "master" $y$ which is the additive inverse of **every** $x$. This is a much stronger claim, which of course is false. In general, $\exists y \forall x$ is a stronger assertion than $\forall x\exists y$ (*stronger*: less likely to be true)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The symbolic expressions are there precisely to make those distinctions *unambiguous*. It is good that you have noticed the possibility of ambiguity, because then you're more than halfway to learning how the notation *resolves* that ambiguity.

It may help a bit to write down the claim with more parentheses:
$$ \forall x\in\mathbb N \Big( \exists y\in\mathbb N (x+y=0)\Big)$$
This extra set of brackets doesn't change the meaning; it is how chained quantifiers are *always* interpreted. Then we can unravel the quantifiers one my one.

> For every natural number $x$ it is true that
>   $$ \exists y \in\mathbb N (x+y=0) $$

The symbolic formula $\exists y\in\mathbb N(x+y)=0$ contains the variable $x$ but does not bind that variable -- so it is an *open formula* that denotes a property that some specific $x$ can have or not have. Namely, the property "you can add something to it to make it zero".

In other words, the formula $\exists y\in\mathbb N(x+y=0)$ only becomes true or false when we select a value for $x$. Once we do so, it turns into one of
$$ \exists y\in\mathbb N(0+y=0) \\ \exists y\in\mathbb N(1+y=0) \\ \exists y\in\mathbb N(2+y=0) \\ \cdots $$
And the truth values of each of *those* doesn't care about *how* we produced it. Each of them can be evaluated by itself, and the $\exists y$ in one of them is independent of the fact that there's another $\exists y$ somewhere else on the paper.

Here we see that $\exists y\in\mathbb N(0+y=0)$ is true (we can take $y=0$), but the other formulas are false (there is no $y\in\mathbb N$ that becomes 0 when you add 1 or 2).

Now we can go back to the $\forall x$. It asserted that all of the *different* $\exists y$ formulas are true, which is not the case, and therefore the entire $\forall x\exists y\ldots$ formula is false.

What this all works out to when the dust settles is that

> - When a $\exists$ appears *to the right of* $\forall$, the $\exists$-bound variable is allowed to depend on the $\forall$-bound variable.
> - When the $\exists$ appears *to the left of* $\forall$, there must be a single value for the $\exists$-bound variable that works for all choices of $\forall$.

Typically you would just be asked to memorize these two shortcut rules. But I think it is easier to know *how* the rules arise -- namely by putting in the parentheses and treating one quantifier at a time.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, but at a certain point you lost me... 
So, if I take the expression $\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{N}: \exists y\in\mathbb{N}: (x+y=0)$, this asserts that for every $x$, there are several $y$'s that make this expression hold? Or does it assert that for every $x$, there is *one*, *unique* $y$ that makes this expression hold?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: It asserts that for every $x$ there is _at least one_ $y$ that makes $x+y=0$ hold for that particular $x$.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: Another way to think of it is a game: Your opponent starts by revealing a $x$ -- if you can then play an $y$ such that $x+y=0$, you win that round of the game. It doesn't matter whether there are more than one $y$ you can play, as long as there is one. The entire $\forall\exists$ formula is then true if you have a winning strategy that the opponent cannot beat by choosing his $x$ cleverly. On the other hand, in an $\exists y\forall x$ game, _you_ start by writing down an $y$, and your _opponent_ then chooses and $x$ and you win the round if $x+y=0$ turns out to be true.

Comment: So, the first claim two claims I originally posted are then true?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: No, the first claim is _false_: When $x=1$ there is _no_ $y\in\mathbb N$ such that $x+y=0$. But the claim asserts that such an $y$ can be found _no matter what $x$ is_, which is not the case.

Comment: Ok. That's a mistake on my part for being too hasty and not paying attention to details. I just want to clarify these meanings with you one last time in layman terms so that I know that I have it down. 

So, $\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{N}: \exists y\in\mathbb{N}: (x+y=0)$ basically means that given any $x$ in the natural numbers, there is a $y$ in the natural numbers that will make the expression (is it called the predicate?) hold. So if you give me some random $x$ in the natural numbers, I will be able to give you a $y$ that makes the expression hold.

Comment: On the other hand, $\quad \exists y\in\mathbb{N}: \forall x\in\mathbb{N}: (x+y=0)$ means that given one specific $y$, and every $x$ in the natural numbers, the expression will hold. (Which is impossible).

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: Yes, that sounds right.

Answer (score 4):

It means that for any $x$ (in the set), there is at least one $y$ (in the set) such that $x+y=0$.

Informally, given an $x$ in the set, we can find a suitable $y=y(x)$ in the set, such that the relation holds.

"The" $y$ is specific to $x$, in the sense that different $x$ may require different $y$. When we assert $\forall x\exists yP(x,y)$, we are not claiming that given $x$ there is a unique $y$ (dependent on $x$) such that $P(x,y)$ holds. There may be several.

Contrast this with the *very different* sentence $\exists y\forall xP(x,y)$. This means that there is a $y$ that works uniformly for every $x$, what you called a master key.

Comment: Can I give you my interpretation (in layman terms) of what you said, and then you tell me if I'm right or correct me where I'm wrong (if I am).

Comment: Of course. go ahead.  I will be in and out today, in long enough to sustain a conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(x, y)$ be some sentence involving variables $x$ and $y$.

Then $\forall x\ \exists y\ P(x, y)$ means that for any $x$, there is at least one $y$ such that $P(x, y)$ is true. The $y$ is allowed to be different for each $x$. For example:

$$(\forall x\in\text{Humanity}\ \exists y\in\text{Humanity})\ \text{$y$ is $x$'s father}$$

Notice that $y$ is not the same for all $x$. If we wanted to say there was *one* $y$ that worked for everyone, we would say:

$$\exists y\ \forall x\ P(x, y)$$